# When I double click a folder in Windows Explorer it opens Visual Studio

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Windows 10 x64. When I double click a folder in Windows Explorer it opens Visual Studio.

It doesn't happen all the time and not always for a given folder.

It happens usually like this.

I am working away in Windows Explorer, then when I double click a given folder I get an error message dialog "An internal error occurred".

Then I double click the folder again and nothing happens.

Then I click off the folder and on it and can go in.

Then I back out and with the same original folder if I right click several times in a row, the context menu changes each time. Sometimes it has the default action for that folder as 7Zip, then Visual Studio, then no default action, just copy and paste options on the context menu.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, but I have found that restarting explorer cures the issue for a while.  It  seems to be worst when the machine has been running for a week. or more.

Comment: Yes that is probably true. Perhaps the reason I am not seeing it as much now is that I have a Windows Sleep issue that restarts my computer unexpectedl;y and frequently... that could have been an MS patch to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem might lie in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`

If there's a key in there like `AnyCode` with subkey `command`, that might be what's launching Visual Studio. It would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJF9k.png) in `regedit`. I [deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wKhM.png) it and the problem went away. If you're going to do this, make sure you know what you're doing and back up your registry because I don't want to be held responsible for registry damages.

Comment: Thanks.There was also a lot of other weird Windows 10 file association errors going on. I have reloaded windows twice and resorted to getting a new PC. I will try this out though as some other people at work have reported a similar thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to elevate Code Gorilla's comment to a full answer, as it solved the problem for me, and is much safer than prying into the registry.

> I have the same issue, but I have found that restarting explorer cures the issue for a while. It seems to be worst when the machine has been running for a week. or more. – Code Gorilla Aug 19 '19 at 9:59

I develop on a virtual machine using java and Eclipse. Recently I have seen this behaviour, which is why I am here. Visual Studio is installed on my virtual machine, but I have never opened it on purpose.

I was using that explorer window for testing, and it had been open for about a week when I noticed Visual Studio starting when I double click to enter a folder. Restarting explorer cured the issue.